# How to set a image as background Textbox Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to set an image as background Textbox in Corona.  Help me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try set

```
obj.hasBackground = false
```

and then simply display the background color/image you want in the position of the field.

I think it can not be tested on Corona sim. Use real device.